# getting error while using window.ethereum in Next Js with ether JS

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, ethereum, ethers.js

Having Issues while using the `window.ethereum` with NextJs new version, The `window.ethereum` was working fine with the NextJs 12 but when I upgraded to NextJs 13 having this error. Is there any alternative for this?

[image]

Code:-

```
 const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);

 const signer = provider.getSigner();

 console.log(signer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `npm i --save-dev @ethersproject/providers`.

```
import { ExternalProvider } from "@ethersproject/providers";

useEffect(() => {
    async function load() {
      try {
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(
          window.ethereum as unknown as ExternalProvider
        );
       // you get variables
       // then setstate inside useState
      }
```

proof of work:

[image]

Comment: I tried now getting `window is not defined`.

Comment: I run inside `useEffect` where `window` will be defined. you can have this if statement `if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  add your code here
}`

Answer (score 0):

I also run on the same
issue using NextJS, but after trying and searching. I find this solution to work better for me.

```
const [provider, setProvider] = useState({});

useEffect( async () => {
    if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined' || (typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined')) {
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
        setProvider(provider);
        // other stuff using provider here
    }
}, []);
```

link to Reference [ether-io](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/726)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ethers` version `6.0.0`+ then have a look on my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75477045/9784839) here. I think its the newer version issue.