# Nextjs 13.0.2 and Ethers why is my Provider undefined?

Tags: next.js, ethereum, blockchain, smartcontracts, ethers.js

I'm trying to access the ethers provider like this in Nextjs 13.0.1:

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";

export const signMessage = () => {
  
  const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
  const signer = provider.getSigner();

  try {
    signer.signMessage("Hey hey").then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

But it always gives me the error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Web3Provider')
```

I've tried different providers but always get the error message above.

Someone knows why it's working for Nextjs 12 but not for Next 13?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are using version 6 in next13. if you install

```
"ethers": "^5.6.4",
```

in next-13, it will work.

I think you previously had next-12 project with version 5, and now installing new version on next-13

in `ethers v6` all of those

```
export {
    getDefaultProvider,
    Block, FeeData, Log, TransactionReceipt, TransactionResponse,
    AbstractSigner, NonceManager, VoidSigner,
    AbstractProvider,
    FallbackProvider,
    JsonRpcApiProvider, JsonRpcProvider, JsonRpcSigner,

    BrowserProvider,
    AlchemyProvider, AnkrProvider, CloudflareProvider, EtherscanProvider,
    InfuraProvider, PocketProvider, QuickNodeProvider,
    IpcSocketProvider, SocketProvider, WebSocketProvider,
    EnsResolver,
    Network
} from "./providers/index.js";
```

are imported like this

```
import { BrowserProvider } from "ethers";

const providerr = new BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
```

this is how I set a component to connect

```
const Test = () => {
  const [provider, setProvider] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    const browserProvider = new BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
    setProvider(browserProvider);
  }, []);
  const connect = async () => {
    await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts");
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={connect}>connect</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Comment: OMG!!! I was trying to debug the entire day...  you're a day safer! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `"ethers": "^6.0.2"` like me then use this :

```js
const web3Provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
```

Also then getting `signer` you should remember that `web3Provider.getSigner()` will return a promise so use `await` or `then`

```js
const signer = await web3Provider.getSigner();
```

Check more on [`ethers` documentation](https://docs.ethers.org/v6/getting-started/)