# ethers.js `const accounts = await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);` gives wrong data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, metamask, ethers.js

I am trying to connect my react frontend to metamask wallet using ethers library.

While trying to do so I came upon 2 methods to do so:

```
const accounts = provider.listAccounts();
const accounts2 = await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
```

Earlier, I was using accounts2 methods and it is fetching my public address, but converts all character to lowercase

Here, I am attaching the images:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
const signer = provider.getSigner();
const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractAbi, signer);
```

[image: Connect Wallet function using ethers]

[image: after 64, everything is in lowercase]

What might be causing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nextjs 13.0.2 and Ethers why is my Provider undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75351780/nextjs-13-0-2-and-ethers-why-is-my-provider-undefined)

Comment: No, I want to know why I am getting my account key changed by the 2nd method as attached in the images.